# Re-adding removed elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

> Note that there is not currently a dedicated API to add removed elements back to the document; however, you can pass a function to selection.append or selection.insert to re-add elements.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

What is meant by passing a function? I am not sure how to go about implement this. I tried passing an function that appends the removed div back to the parent, but didnot work. Any ideas?

This is a relatively new feature in d3.

Comment: What did you try? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a function that returns the DOM element to append`

So you could simply do something like:

```
d3.select("body").append(function() {
    return document.createElement("div");
});
```

Instead of simply using the string name

```
d3.select("body").append("div");
```

When you are using d3 selectors, keep in mind they are not single elements. They are an array of groups. Thus, if you said:

```
var divs = d3.select("div").remove(); // actually a multidimensional array
var firstElement = divs[0][0]; // this can be appended by returning it
```

The relevant text from Mike is: `One nuance is that selections are grouped: rather than a one-dimensional array, each selection is an array of arrays of elements`

Here is a simple working [fiddle to show a *very* basic example.](http://jsfiddle.net/dinkleburg/jKYTD/)

Comment: Thanks, does that mean when applying an attribute to a selection, then all its sub-elements get the same attribute as well? For example `d3.selectAll("path").attr("visibility", "hidden")`, will that affect the 2nd, 3rd, etc subgroups?

Comment: Yea, those apply to the groups. I believe the issue is really that `append` doesn't allow you to append a collection. Data driven `enter` is more for that.